# Open Api code generator maven plug in tag details

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, openapi, openapi-generator

Below is my open api code gen maven plug in

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>server</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/games.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                        <apiPackage>com.tintin.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.tintin.model</modelPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <supportingFilesToGenrate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenrate>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

*What is the difference between configuration and configOption tags. And which options to place inside whic tags?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<configuration>` elements aims to provide configuration for your plugin i.e. the `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:x.y.z` in your case.
The `<configuration>` element is a standard plugin tag that aims to encapsulate a plugin configuration as a whole. It is a general element that can host any sub-elements of any shape and is common to all plugins.

The `<configOptions>` on the other hand is a plugin, i.e. `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:x.y.z`, specific element that declares configuration properties specific to the plugin it self.
This is a non-standard tag and has to be mapped to a particular field in the plugin `XXXMojo.java` type.
[Here you can see the mapping](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/plugin/CodeGenMojo.java#L280):

```java
public class CodeGenMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    // other properties
    
    /**
     * A map of language-specific parameters as passed with the -c option to the command line
     */
    @Parameter(name = "configOptions")
    private Map<?, ?> configOptions;

    // ...
}
```